# Filter select list items based on selected items within the loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ngRepeat directive on a table that loops through some items with each item having a Name field.

I have a select list in a table cell in this loop and that select list has a list of Names.

> Example parent list (**SelectedPeople**):  { "Name": "asdfasdfasdf" }
>
> Each select list (**People**): [ { "Name": "John Smith" }, { "Name": "Jane Smith"
>   }, { "Name": "Bill Gates" }, { "Name": "asdfasdfasdf" } ]

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="selectedPeople in SelectedPeople">
        <td>
            <select ng-model="selectedPeople.SelectedPeople.Name" ng-options="people.Name as people.Name for people in People"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*(Ignore syntax errors in the above json, it's just an example)*

How can I filter the select list to **NOT** add items already selected in the table?

Example: *(in the image below)* The "asdfasdfasdf" item **shouldn't** appear in the select list.

[image: Example of select list within ngRepeat]

I simply do not know how to write the filter for this.  Any help would be appreciated and I hope this made sense.  :)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$scope.inListFilter = function(person) {
  return (SelectedPeople.indexOf(person) !== -1);
}
```

And then the html:

```
<select ng-model="selectedPeople.SelectedPeople.Name" ng-options="person.Name as person.Name for person in People | filter:inListFilter"></select>
```

You pass in the object to the filter function, and then run tests on it and return true or false depending on whether you want it filtered out or not. This will check if it's in the list and return false if it is, thus filtering it out.